# undefined path i variable c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I can't find where my path isn't defined in my variable. When I am debugging I see the path name in my expressions.

How can I change this?

Here is a part of my code:

```
private static string getPDFfilename(document theDoc)
        {

           string fullPathFilename = theDoc.MultiPagePdfFile;
            string filenameWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(fullPathFilename);
            return filenameWithoutPath;


        }


        private static byte[] getEmbbeddedObj(document theDoc)
        {

                string filenameWithoutPath = theDoc.MultiPagePdfFile;
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filenameWithoutPath);


                return bytes;

       }
```

errors

> theDoc.MultiPagePdfFile = "E:\Ephesoft\final-drop-folder\Decoline\BI1450\LINDER SA_86846_DOC1.pdf"
>
> filenameWithoutPath = "E:\Ephesoft\final-drop-folder\Decoline\BI1450\LINDER SA_86846_DOC1.pdf"

Comment: Change it to do what? What are you trying to achieve here? In the second method, you call a variable filenameWithoutPath, but it's just the full path from the theDoc object (terrible name btw). Whereas, you call Path.GetFileName() in the first to get the "filenameWithoutPath". Is that your issue?

Comment: You do a `string filenameWithoutPath = theDoc.MultiPagePdfFile;` in the other function without actually calling your `getPDFfilename()` function. `Path.GetFileName()` should work fine by itself.

Comment: Yeeah... you're not actually calling `getPDFfilename()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on variable name 'filenameWithoutPath', you went to have name of your file without path. if its true, use FileInfo in System.IO namespace.